# After adding a new column on my table I can't insert data anymore

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm doing something like a posting tool and it was working fine with the data being inserted on the database. I decided adding the field *link* and this error appeared:

**Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pequeno Davi 2 Versão completa\Painel de postagens\armazenar_postagens.php on line 23**

My code:

```
<body>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="well well-sm">
                <div id="panel">
                    <form action="armazenar_postagens.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <h4>Escolha uma imagem de capa</h4>
                        <p><input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form form-control"/></p>
                        <h4>Título da publicação</h4>
                        <p><input type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo" placeholder="Insira um título" class="form form-control"/></p>
                        <h4>Texto da publicação</h4>
                        <p><textarea name="descricao" id="descricao" placeholder="Texto da publicação" class="form form-control"></textarea></p>
                        <h4>Link</h4>
                        <p><input type="text" name="link" id="link" placeholder="Insira o endereço de um link" class="form form-control"/></p>
                        <h4>Adicione uma imagem para o corpo da publicação</h4>
                        <p><input type="file" name="image_imagem" id="image_imagem" class="form form-control"/></p>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Publicar</button>
                    </form>
                    <!--<?php
                        //if($campo_vazio == 1){
                            //echo '<font color="#FF0000">Você não preencheu algum dos campos!</font>';
                        //}
                    ?> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>

        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
```

```
<?php

    require_once('db.class.php');

    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
    $link = $_POST['link'];

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $data = date("d/m/Y");
    $hora = date("H:i");

    $uploaddir = 'imagens/uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $imagename = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    $objDb = new db();
    $link = $objDb-> conecta_mysql ();


    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)){
        echo "Imagem enviada com sucesso";
            $sql = "INSERT INTO postagens(titulo, descricao, data, hora, imagem_capa, link) VALUES ('$titulo', '$descricao', '$data', '$hora', '$imagename', '$link')";
            echo'<img src="'.$imagename.'"/>' ;
        if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
            if(empty($titulo) || empty($descricao)){
                header('Location: Ferramenta_postagem.php?campo_vazio=1');
            }else{
                header('Location: Ferramenta_postagem.php');
            }

        } else {
            echo 'Erro ao registrar postagem!';
            echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($link));
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: What I don't get is why you're querying in an `if` and then checking if some of the variables are empty inside that conditional statement.

Comment: Can you post the result of `desc postagens`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line causes the problem

```
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
```

You defined at the start

```
$link = $_POST['link'];
```

And in the middle
you used following code

```
 $link = $objDb-> conecta_mysql ();
```

Where used the **same** varaible name

but mysqli_query($link expects a mysql connection instead of your $Link defined at the start

Exchange $link  with  $conn  and use that in

```
$conn = $objDb-> conecta_mysql ();
----
mysqli_query($conn,sql
```

And please read up on **prepared statements** because of **sql injection**

Answer (score 0):

Change your database connection variable $link.

You used this variable ($link) in POST method for data input, and also use database connection variable

```
$link = $objDb-> conecta_mysql ();
```

Change this variable like this:

```
$connect = $objDb-> conecta_mysql ();
```

If you change this variable then you should also change those line

```
if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql)){
```

And

```
echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($connect));
```